# protection level for model attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, encapsulation

Suppose the following situation

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  private
  def password= p
    self[:password] = p
  end

  def password
    self[:password]
  end
end
```

If anyone with access to the Rails console can do:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
2.0.0p247 :001 > User
 => User(id: integer, name:string, password:string)
2.0.0p247 :002 > u = User.find(1)
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Jack", password: "da6c253ffe0975ca1ddd92865ff3d5f0">
2.0.0p247 :003 > u.password = "123"
NoMethodError: private method 'password' called for #<User:0xa9145b0>
2.0.0p247 :004 > u[:password] = "123"
 => "123"
2.0.0p247 :005 > u
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Jack", password: "123">
2.0.0p247 :005 > u.save
 => true
```

Why does this happen? How can I encapsulate critical fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that `password` is `attr_accessible` in the model.  When a field is `attr_accessible`, Rails automatically lets you read and write to the field.  You have a private password method that overwrites the Rails `password` and `password=` methods, but you did not overwrite the `[]` and `[]=` methods as well.  You can either overwrite the `[]` and `[]=` methods or make it so `password` is not `attr_accessible`.

Here is a code example of how to overwrite the `[]` method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def [](word)
    puts "I am the master of: #{word}"
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    puts "Fluffy monsters"
  end
end
```

With this revised code, here is what the `[]` method will return:

```
>> u[:password] = "123"
=> nil
# prints "Fluffy monsters" in the console

>> u[:password]
=> nil
# prints "I am the master of: password" in the console
```

Comment: I can declare `[]=(key, value)` and `[](word)` as private (`private :[], :[]=`) but I have another problem. Suppose that `User` belongs to some object, let's say `belongs_to: group` so when I call `some_user.group` I get `NoMethodError: private method '[]' called for #<User:0x88658b4>`. If I overriden as you say, always is nil. Seems to be that the fields cannot be private or protected in rails. :(

Comment: @Overflow012 - password should not be `attr_accessible` in Rails.  It creates a mass assignment security hole.  Just make it so password is not `attar_accessible` and that should solve all your problems :)