# Overriding attribute accessors on Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-accessor

I have a Restriction model that represent a `formula`. The field `formula` is a string that at runtime is evaluated. This field can't be accessed from outside for security reasons so I'am trying to override the accessors.

```
class Restriction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :indicator
  RESTRICTION_TYPES = {
    less_than: "IND<X", 
    greater_than: "X<IND", 
    between: "X<IND && IND<Y"
  }

  def evaluate(number)
    f = formula.gsub("IND", "#{number}")
    eval(f)
  end

  def create_formula(type_name, arg)
    if(type_name == :between)
      f = RESTRICTION_TYPES[:between].gsub("X", "#{arg[0]}").gsub("Y", "#{arg[1]}")
    else
      f = RESTRICTION_TYPES[type_name].gsub("X", "#{arg}")
    end
    formula = f
  end


  private
  def formula= f
    write_attribute(:formula, f)
  end

  def formula
    read_attribute(:formula)
  end

  def [](value)
    super[value]    
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    super[key] = value
  end

end
```

In rails console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
2.0.0p247 :001 > r = Restriction.new
 => #<Restriction id: nil, formula: nil, indicator_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, state: nil> 
2.0.0p247 :002 > r.create_formula(:between, [1,2])
 => "1<IND && IND<2" 
2.0.0p247 :003 > r.evaluate 1.5
NoMethodError: undefined method 'gsub' for nil:NilClass
2.0.0p247 :004 > r
 => #<Restriction id: nil, formula: nil>
```

`formula` is not change the value. What am I doing wrong?

**PS:** You can see that I have also overriden `[](value)` and `[]=(key, value)`. This is due to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023901/protection-level-for-model-attributes-in-rails/18024282?noredirect=1#18024282)

Answer (score 1):

Rails internally relies on the hash like access methods for reading and writing attributes. By making them private you wanted to restrict the access of [] and []= to from within the object only. But you destroyed the method, because you are using super the wrong way. When calling `super` you are not getting the super object of this class, but the super method, the current method overrides. Thus change it like this and it should work:

```
def [](value)
  super(value)
end

def []=(key, value)
  super(key, value)
end
```

P.S.: Overriding a method for declaring it private is overkill in Ruby. You can simply declare it private with

```
private :[], []=
```

Comment: Now I can set the `formula` field! :). I added `private :[], :[]=` as you say but if I run `some_restriction.indicator` I get `NoMethodError: private method '[]' called for #<Restriction:0x88658b4>` Why? `indicator` is a relationship (See the first line) in my model.

Comment: Seems like Rails tries to access the `indicator_id` with Hash syntax, i.e. `object[:indicator_id]`, from outside the object and thus cannot read the attribute. Seems like you cannot declare them private without breaking Rails functionality, I'm sorry for that! I read your previous question why you wanted to declare them private or override them: How big are the chances that someone gets access to a Rails console and can alter your objects via Hash syntax? He needs to get on your server and then read out your database config and directly access your DB. He does not need the console ;)

Comment: Maybe the super class try access to `indicator_id` This means that I can't overriding? :(

Comment: Anyway, I think that it breaks with the encapsulation principle of OOP and a developer may make a bad use of fields.

Comment: Not as far as I can see... But the question is, whether you need it, anyway. Altering objects from the console is not a security issue IMHO.

Comment: Yep, but you will face this problem quite often in Ruby, because it is in its nature. Let's assume you set an instance variable named `@foo` inside any method of your object and don't have any getter for this instance variable. By calling object.instance_variable_get('@foo') you can still access it, **although** there is no getter. As nice as Ruby is, you can do many ugly things with it, if you don't use it right!